# onBlur function not executing

Tags: javascript, onblur

I've been searching for an answer for why this isn't working for several hours, and I'm stumped.

Here's the script including the javascript and form involved.

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function complete(init){
        alert ("in function with " + init);
        var aList = new Array(<?php echo $aList; ?>);
        var iList = new Array(<?php echo $iList; ?>);
        for (var i = 0; i < iList.length; i++){
            if (init == iList[i]){
                alert ("replacing " + init + " with " + aList[i]);
                this.frmMain.txtAtty.value = aList[i];
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<FORM METHOD="POST" NAME="frmMain" ACTION=<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>>
    <table width="75%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td width="25%" align="right">Name:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="txtSender" size="30" value=""/><span class="noteText"> Your Name</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="25%" align="right">Attorney:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="txtAtty" size="30" value="" onblur = "complete(this.value)">
            </td>
        </tr>
```

The two PHP echo statements are the parameters for the Arrays. The complete(this.value) function is supposed to take a 3 letter code (in the iList array) and substitute it with a name. The alerts are in there for debugging purposes, but i don't get either alert when i run the page. Any ideas?

Comment: How do the alist and ilist look like? Should look like "a","b","c". Can you post the rendered html instead of the php

Answer (score 1):

this.frmMain
is not defined anywhere

change

```
onblur = "complete(this.value)"
```

to

```
onblur = "complete(this)"
```

and use

```
function complete(field){
  var init = field.value;
        alert ("in function with " + init);
        var aList = new Array(<?php echo $aList; ?>);
        var iList = new Array(<?php echo $iList; ?>);
        for (var i = 0; i < iList.length; i++){
            if (init == iList[i]){
                alert ("replacing " + init + " with " + aList[i]);
                field.value = aList[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I completely don't know where i got the this.frmMain line from. Looking at it now it's the obvious problem. I suppose I should have used document.frmMain, but I like your solution its much easier to understand.